# Connecting MS Access DB from android via .Net webservice

Tags: web-services, ms-access-2007

I have a web service connected to MS Access 2007. Web service runs on the localhost. Android application uses this service. When it comes to call method which will retrieve the data, some errors occurs:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The server is unable to
>   process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine.

Other methods of the service, which are not connected to db, work well on android. Also, all methods works well on the explorer.

Are there any suggestions to solve this problem?

Regards..

Comment: Well you usually google for things like that mate http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to install Microsoft Access redistributable, you may try this one http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255